# Getting - error Error: Please install pg package manually when using sequelize with NextJS

Tags: next.js, sequelize.js, next.js13

Using nextjs 13.4.7, typescript 5.1.3, sequelize ^6.32.1, sequelize-typescript ^2.1.5 & postgres/sqlite (pg ^8.11.1 pg-hstore ^2.3.4 and sqlite3 ^5.1.6).

Getting this error when navigating to a route that calls an API that calls sequelize.findBy.

- error Error: Please install pg package manually
- error Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually

(Depending on which dialect I'm using).

Tried:

- npm rebuild
- rm -rf node_modules && npm i && npm rebuild
- Using yarn instead

Help :(

Example repo to run:
https://gitlab.com/shaundavin.se/minimally-reproducible-repo

Using node v20.3.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was to do

```
export const sequelize = new Sequelize(databaseURL, {
  dialectModule: pg,
  dialect: 'postgres'
});
```

Doesn't fix the warning that `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression` but good enough for now.